# Accent in my user folder generates an error in execution of read_csv()

Tags: r

I'm having trouble executing the routine `read_csv()`, I'm pretty sure it is because my user folder has an accent and that gives an 'file not found' error:

```
> statics <-read_csv("statics.csv")
```

> Error: Timezone database not found at
> "C:/Users/AdministraciÃ©n/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/tzdb/tzdata"

In the route there is a 'Ã©' that I assume is causing the problem. I can't change the name of my user folder without making many of the programs of my system crash, so I don't know how to solve this... Any ideas how to solve it?

I tried editing the environmental variables, setting:

> R_LIBS_USER  C:/Users/Administración/Documents/R/win-library/4.1

And with this, as before, I can load libraries as `tidyverse`, installed there, without problems, but when I use that `read_csv()` routine crashes because it searches it in the folder changing the accent for those strange character.

Answer (score 0):

The two symbols you are using in your pathway aren't recognized by R.

R can recognize them with the unicode symbol.
Ã is "\u0200" in R code
© is "\u00a9" in R code

Does this work with your pathway?

```
setwd(paste("C:/Users/Administraci","\u0200","\u00a9","n/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/tzdb/tzdata",sep=""))
read_csv("statics.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you Yacine. Unfortunately, that would not solve the error, because the problem is in the search of a library that's in the win-library folder, not in opening an archive in my working directory.

In fact, my working directory is set with the accent and works correctly:

Dir <- "C:/Users/Administración/Desktop/wk"
setwd(file.path(Dir))

But for some reason, the default direction to search for those library is set with the strange characters and I don't know where to change it, I only found the place to change the directory of the R version. Other libraries are found without errors